# C++: Cannot use designated initializers on extended structs/classes

Tags: c++, c++20

I am trying to figure out a way to use designated initializers to build a struct, which has been extended off of another one. In my use case, the struct `S` is a domain object, and the struct `S2` adds some application-specific logic for converting it to/from json. As far as I can tell, you cannot use designated initializers if you have a "real" constructor, but all is well if you have a static method returning a new instance for you.

I have a MVP like so ([view in Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/aKejcznKq)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int i;
};

struct S2 : public S {
    static S2 create() {
        return S2 { .i = 1234 };
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << S2::create().i;
}
```

When building (using `-std=c++20`), I get the following error:

```
<source>:9:31: error: 'S2' has no non-static data member named 'i'
    9 |         return S2 { .i = 1234 };
      |                               ^
```

I expect that the `i` field would be carried over and initialized, but it isn't.

Am I trying to do something C++ cannot support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is data member of `S`, but not `S2`.

You can add another braces referring to the base subobject, e.g.

```
return S2 { {.i = 1234} };
```

Or you can just take advantage of brace elision:

```
return S2 { 1234 };
```